# how get Drawable from String path?

Tags: android

I have String field with Drawable image, this image is in @Drawable folder
I have only a String path!

I want to ask how I can retrieve my image from a path, because getDrawable is deprecated

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(drawableImage);
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableImage, null, getActivity().getPackageName());
weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imageResource));
```

how I can do? getDrawable is deprecated

Comment: Add more description on what you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getDrawable()` is deprecated and the alternative is

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***);
```

But if you have a `String` name of the Image. Then here is what you have to do:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("image_name_in_drawable_folder", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Do not put the full path from the Uri. Just put the identifier name only the image name only.

Comment: ok ok, i understand  but i dont have R.drawable.***    i have String url = "R.drawable.***";     how i can do?

Comment: I dont get you but Is that drawable present in your project files Drawable folder???

Comment: i try... i used: String drawableImage = "q"+urlImage;
                    
                    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableImage, null, getActivity().getPackageName());
                    weatherIcon.setImageDrawable(   (ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), imageResource)));

Comment: If your drawable is in Drawable folder then you should use R.drawable.your_drawable_name. I dont get it when you say you have a string path while the drawable is in your apk??

Comment: i takeDown image's name from JSON file... is a String, this String is: 01, so i need to add some letter before and put .pgn to have the resource image to retrieve in my Drawable folder... yes i store all the possibility image in my Drawable folder! and i dont know how to do!

Comment: Dont save image names in json as tring save integers for example R.drawable.your_image is an `int` save that integer instead of a name as a string its hard to convert back because android consider it as an int. So take each R.drawable.image save that as an integer and not a string. Dont put double qoutes.

Comment: i really dont understand... i have image, that i saved in Drawable folder... after i retrieve name to JSON, i built right name (put letter before and .png) as a String (because i have only String)...... i need to retrieve this image THAT I ALREADY HAVE!!!!!!!!!! i cannot understand (or i dont know i suppose) how i can save int value for the images! how i can save integer instead of a name as a String.... this i dont understand!! thankYouSoMuchForThisHelpl

Comment: Okay lets go slowly where does you take the json from?. Is it from internet?

Comment: I have updated my answer please see if it works @francescofreddi

Comment: i have String drawableImage = urlImage+"q"+iconaMeteo+".png";    that is: R.Drawable.q10d.png.... this image is in Drawable folder... when i do:  int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableImage, null, getActivity().getPackageName());  to retrieve int resource (like your suggest) crash!! :(

Comment: So take each R.drawable.image save that as an integer and not a string.............. i cannot understand! really....

Comment: to sum up:
i need to retrieve image in my Drawable folder from String name: R.Drawable.q10d.png
i dont know how i can do! (i am in a Fragment class, if is need it)

Comment: Using a string I have updated and edit my answer. Check above in place of `image_name_in_drawable_folder` put there only the name `q10d` and if it doesnt work put `q10d.png` but I think it will work with just `q10d`. Check the answer above I have edited it.

Comment: i try... is always 0!!!  int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("q01d", null, getActivity().getPackageName());  or i try... is always 0!!!  int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("q01d.png", null, getActivity().getPackageName());  :(

Comment: function functio: int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableImage, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());  with this all functionnnnn yuhhuuuuu thankYouSoMuchForHelp, i love you!!! francesco

Comment: Okay @francescofreddi but because my solution has solved your problem then you have to Accept it as an answer by putting a tick to it. And you are the only one who can do that. This was your question.

Comment: votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do no change the the publicly displayed post score...... i am :(

Comment: Dont vote just put a tick! You can vote for now!

Comment: ok, i do, i think :)

Comment: Okay. Good and thanks!